# Module uncallable in Python?

Tags: python

I've run into an error with Python. Please see the code examples below. I run `event_timer.py` and I get the following error message. Both of the files listed below are in the same folder.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\python\event_timer\event_timer.py", line 7, in 
    timer = EventTimer()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

What am I missing?

**event_timer.py:**

```
import EventTimer

timer = EventTimer()

timer.addStep("Preheat Oven", seconds = 10)
timer.addStep("Cook Pizza", seconds = 20)
timer.addStep("Done!")

timer.start()
```

**EventTimer.py:**

```
import time

class Timer:

    event = 'Event'
    steps = []

    def __init__(self, event = None):

        if event is not None:

            self.event = event

    def addStep(self, step, seconds = None, minutes = None, hours = None, days = None):

        if seconds is not None:

            unit = 'seconds'
            amount = seconds

        elif minutes is not None:

            unit = 'minutes'
            amount = minutes

        elif hours is not None:

            unit = 'hours'
            amount = hours

        elif days is not None:

            unit = 'days'
            amount = days

        else:

            print 'Invalid arguments'

            return False

        self.steps.append({'unit': unit, 'amount': amount})

        return True

    def __timeInSeconds(self, unit, amount):

        if unit == 'seconds':

            return amount

        elif unit == 'minutes':

            return amount * 60

        elif unit == 'hours':

            return amount * 60 * 60

        elif unit == 'days':

            return amount * 60 * 60 * 24

        else:

            print 'Invalid unit'

            return False

    def start(self):

        if len(self.steps) == 0:

            print 'No steps to complete'

            return False

        print "{0} has started.".format(self.event)

        for step in self.steps:

            print step.step

            time.sleep(self.__timeInSeconds(step.unit, step.amount))

            print "Completed"

        print 'Event complete'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you write

```
import EventTimer
```

you make a new variable, `EventTimer`, pointing to a *module* -- the module that you've just written! Inside that module is a class, `Timer`. So to make an instance of that class, you do

```
timer = EventTimer.Timer()
```

Comment: Also, change your code to: `from EventTimer import Timer; timer = Timer()`

Comment: @hughdbrown: Possible, but rarely useful and sometimes even dangerous or unnecessarily verbose.

Comment: Actually, I meant the OP should do that. But while we're on it, dangerous? Rarely useful to specify what you are importing and making it minimal?

Comment: @hugh: I don't think it's dangerous, any more than any other way of binding a name, but I think it's less explicit, since it is no longer clear that the contents of the variable were defined elsewhere. `Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!`